# Simple login form according to the items in object.Multiple object

Tags: javascript, arrays, oop, object, authentication

I need help in my task. Login and password inputs should check has object got items to sign in. Can someone tell me how to create a multiple object with a lot of logins and pass within? I tried but failed. I don't get even how to get the username from array in object. Waiting for answers <3

```
var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
var users = {
  userlist: [
    {
      username: "a",
      password: "a"
    },
    {
      username: "b",
      password: "b"
    }
  ]
};

console.log(users.userlist[username]);
```

Comment: Have you written *any* code that processes arrays?

Comment: @PM 77-1 yes i did

Comment: try `console.log(users.userlist[1][username]);`